# Redirecting with trailing slash with yoast SEO plugin

Tags: redirect

I want to redirect a page with trailing slashes with yoast seo plugin. But, when I input www.my-site-domain/de/bilder-gallerie/ and click on 'Update Redirect' button, then it will convert www.my-site-domain/de/bilder-gallerie. That means, this input(link) will convert without trailing slash.  e.g. www.my-site-domain/de/bilder-gallerie/ converted to www.my-site-domain/de/bilder-gallerie.

[image]

I want to keep www.my-site-domain/de/bilder-gallerie/ in input field.

Please help me.